# Bot fails to authenticate after restart with saved conversation reference and calling trustServiceUrl

Tags: typescript, authentication, botframework, microsoft-teams

After a user installs my Teams app and bot I capture the initial conversation event and send a notification to the users main channel using that reference.

However, if I restart my server and run the same code, I get an error that the bot is not authorized.

I am calling `MicrosoftAppCredentials.trustedServiceUrl()` right before calling `turnContext.sendActivity()` as specified in the docs https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/16.proactive-messages#avoiding-permission-related-errors . And calling `MicrosoftAppCredentials.isTrustedServiceUrl` returns `true` right before I call `turnContext.sendActivity`.

I basically copied the code from this project for my implementation.

```
{ Error: Authorization has been denied for this request.
    at new RestError (...../node_modules/@azure/ms-rest-js/lib/restError.ts:18:5)
    at ..../node_modules/@azure/ms-rest-js/lib/policies/deserializationPolicy.ts:117:27
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)
  code: undefined,
  statusCode: 401,
  request: 
   WebResource {
     streamResponseBody: false,
     url: 'https://smba.trafficmanager.net/amer/v3/conversations/{convo ID}%40thread.skype/activities/{activiyID}',
     method: 'POST',
     headers: HttpHeaders { _headersMap: [Object] },
     body: '{"type":"message","serviceUrl":"https://smba.trafficmanager.net/amer/","channelId":"msteams","from":{"id":"{ID}","name":"CrossLead Dev Local"},"conversation":{"isGroup":true,"conversationType":"channel","id":"{ID}","tenantId":"{ID}"},"recipient":{"id":"{ID}","aadObjectId":"{ID}"},"text":"The bot encountered an error or bug.","inputHint":"acceptingInput","replyToId":"{ID}"}',
     query: undefined,
     formData: undefined,
     withCredentials: false,
     abortSignal: undefined,
     timeout: 0,
     onUploadProgress: undefined,
     onDownloadProgress: undefined,
     operationSpec: 
      { httpMethod: 'POST',
        path: 'v3/conversations/{conversationId}/activities/{activityId}',
        urlParameters: [Array],
        requestBody: [Object],
        responses: [Object],
        serializer: [Object] } },
  response: 
   { body: '{"message":"Authorization has been denied for this request."}',
     headers: HttpHeaders { _headersMap: [Object] },
     status: 401 },
  body: { message: 'Authorization has been denied for this request.' } }
```

This is still my proof of concept implementation so all the values are hardcoded to make it easier.

```
const msBotAdapter = new BotFrameworkAdapter({
  appId: {ID as string}
  appPassword:  {ID as string},
});

//Some people also said to do this, but never used it anywhere. It doesn't seem to help
const msCreditials = new MicrosoftAppCredentials(
  {ID as string},
  {ID as string}
);

//Save Conversation Reference from when the app was installed into teams
const conversationReference: {
  [key: string]: Partial<ConversationReference>;
} = { 
    activityId: '{activity ID}',
    //@ts-ignore
    user: {
      id:
        '{ID}',
      aadObjectId: '{ID}',
    },
    bot: {
      id: '{Bot Id}',
      name: '{Bot Name}',
    },
    //@ts-ignore
    conversation: {
      isGroup: true,
      conversationType: 'channel',
      tenantId: '{tenant ID}',
      id: '19:{ID}@thread.skype',
    },
    channelId: 'msteams',
    serviceUrl: 'https://smba.trafficmanager.net/amer/',
};


const postMessage = async () => {
      MicrosoftAppCredentials.trustServiceUrl(conversationReference.serviceUrl);
      await msBotAdapter.continueConversation(
        conversationReference as any,
        async turnContext => {
          // If you encounter permission-related errors when sending this message, see
          // https://aka.ms/BotTrustServiceUrl
          await turnContext.sendActivity('test message');
        }
      );
}
```

Comment: don't think this is relevant, but your test message doesn't have a closing quote mark

Comment: also think is isn't relevant to the problem, but you shouldn't need to set the "activity id" unless you're replying to a previous activity

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow This is the conversation reference that you get after calling `TurnContext.getConversationReference(activity);` I persist it and re-use the object to initiate a proactive message as shown in the Microsoft Github example.

As far as I know you cannot send a message to a channel without responding to an existing conversation/activity. This is a Teams policy to prevent spam as far as I can tell.  Also I fixed the missing quote, but yes its just a redacted/simplified version of what I'm actually running. I don't actually construct this object, the `{...}` are just placeholders

Comment: So you're partially correct - you definitely need to store a bunch of that stuff, but not the activity itself - you definitely don't need to reply to an existing activity and can start a "new thread" proactively. To do so, you'd just leave off the activity id, I think (not 100% sure on the Node side, I'm a c# guy)

Comment: I used the example given in the github link provided by microsoft. If you don't restart, using the code works fine. I stepped through the code and it doesn't look like the MS library uses the `activiyId` anyway, removing it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the `botbuilder` dependency was outdated. I was running `4.7.2` and the latest is `4.8.0`. It's worrying that such a minor version release will render past versions useless and without any notice.

Comment: We constantly keep updating the botbuilder versions to fix the bugs encountered in the previous versions and suggest using the most updated version. You can also refer to and post any future issues in the Github [repo](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/issues) to get the issue fixed faster.

Comment: Thanks @ranusharao, I did update but I'm worried that if this goes into production a minor update like the one I ran into here could prevent the bot from functioning. Is there something I can follow to be warned about upcoming breaking changes?

Comment: I suggest you can follow https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/releases to see what were the fixes with the latest version released just to verify if the current issue you are facing was solved with the update.