# "Error: Authorization has been denied for this request." when using BotFramework with Teams

Tags: azure, botframework, chatbot, microsoft-teams

I am getting this error when I send message through teams bot. How to configure my authentication on azure app?
I get proper response in Bot emulator when not connected with Azure app. But when connected it fails. Can anyone give me step by step process on how to authenticate users so I can get response on the Teams Bot.
I looked a lot but nobody explains it clearly.

Details of what I am trying to do :

1. Created MS Teams bot using BotFramework
2. I send message on Teams bot which goes to Botframework
3. BotFramework transfers this request to my application using ngrok endpoint
4. My application sends back response to BotFramework
5. BotFramework sends back response to Teams which I see as the Bot's reply

Where the problem is :
on 5th step,
BotFrameWork gives this Error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TEAMS bot in node.js: 'Authorization has been denied for this request' in CreateConversation method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58431605/teams-bot-in-node-js-authorization-has-been-denied-for-this-request-in-create)

Comment: Also you can verify this so reference : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60920689/bot-fails-to-authenticate-after-restart-with-saved-conversation-reference-and-ca

Comment: You can double-check if you are trusting the serviceUrl. Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-proactive-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp#avoiding-401-unauthorized-errors  and https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/bot-docs/issues/1860 for more details.

Comment: The reference link solution is to use MicrosoftAppCredentials.trustServiceUrl(serviceUrl); which is now deprecated.

Comment: Hey, Have you checked out simple [Echo bot sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/02.echo-bot)? Try this out and see if you are getting response.

Comment: @HunaidHanfee-MSFT Same problem in bot sample too

Comment: The botId and Password are those updated in bot channel registration? and Is it connected to Teams?